# How can I tell if 2 or more walls are connected in the Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, viewer

I'm using the Forge Viewer (3D View) to create 2D floor plans from 3D Models (Revit). Using the bounding box of the wall (dbId) I'm getting the middle line (the z coordinate is ignored) and then I draw it in my 2D canvas.

This is the code I'm using for getting the bounding box by dbId:

```
export const getDbId2BoundingBoxMap = (viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D) => {
  const model = viewer.model;

  const fragList = model.getFragmentList();
  const boxes = fragList.fragments.boxes;
  const fragid2dbid = fragList.fragments.fragId2dbId;

  const boundingBoxInfo: any = {};
  let index = 0;

  for (let step = 0; step < fragid2dbid.length; step++) {
    index = step * 6;
    const thisBox = new THREE.Box3(
      new THREE.Vector3(boxes[index], boxes[index + 1], boxes[index + 2]),
      new THREE.Vector3(boxes[index + 3], boxes[index + 4], boxes[index + 5])
    );

    const dbId = fragid2dbid[step];
    boundingBoxInfo[dbId] = thisBox;
  }

  return boundingBoxInfo;
}
```

This works fine, however I want to connect the lines so that there are no spaces in the corners. Right now I'm using a collision detection algorithm to tell if 2 walls are connected, so I can extend/collapse my lines accordingly.

Is there a better way to connect the walls without checking for collision? Is there something in the Viewer API/data that I can use to tell if they are connected? Ideally I would like to retrieve the list of points of the corners so that I can create polylines.

Comment: firstly, Forge web service or Forge Viewer API has not exposed independent clash/collision detective. The data of geometry is mesh (triangle) . BIM360/ACC provides clash detective (Model Coordination API), but that relies on BIM360/ACc environment. In addition, if two walls are adjacent. in theory, they are 'not' clashed. They may be as correct designed (say two walls of a room), so even Model Coordination API might not tell it is a clash.

Comment: While with the mesh (triangle), you may check if the two walls have shared vertices, which could tell they are connected more or less. But if you want to filter out which two walls are connected in a huge model, by checking vertices, that would not work due to the performance issue.